# What is an appropriate name for a property that tells whether a list is empty, single or multiple?

Tags: programming

I have a property in programming which tells whether a list is empty, or has only one element or has more than one element. ( empty, single, multiple ).

I want to know what would be an appropriate name for the property that contains this value?

For example

```
{} -> empty
{"hi"} -> single / singular
{"hi", "bye"} -> multiple / plural
```

I want to know the name of the property that contains those values?

Comment: What's the matter with _size_? `type size {empty, single, multiple}`

Comment: @JohnLawler but `size` represents the accurate quantity already. This this cannot be named as `size`

Comment: So use a different name - `size-type` for instance. Variable names are for the convenience of the programmers who will maintain and debug the code. They are not subject to the rules of English lexical items, unless it can be guaranteed that only English speakers will ever work on the code, which seems silly. It's your code, so use your own naming conventions.

Answer (score 1):

The nearest term you'll probably find is the hypernym **cardinality.**

> *cardinality* [noun] [mathematics]
>
> The number of elements in a set or other grouping, as a property of
> that grouping.

[[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/cardinality)]

This takes values 0, 1, 2, 3 ... rather than 0, 1, many.

Comment: I knew **cardinality** existed but I was looking for alternative which can capture the empty, single and multiple-ness. But thanks anyway.